# How to copy RTF text to clipboard for use in excel

Tags: .net, winforms, excel, clipboard, rtf

Is it possible to copy a rtf string to the clipboard for excel. The formatting should be preserved as much as possible (e.g. text-color).

The following .Net code is used to fill the clipboard

```
var dataObject = new DataObject();
dataObject.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, rtf);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data_object);
```

1. Excel refuses the rtf clipboard content
2. MS Word accepts the rtf content.
3. When i paste into MSWord and copy from MSWord into Excel it works.

What's the best way to convert the rtf to a format that excel accepts ?

Remarks:
  As @KreepN has suggested, System.Windows.Documents.TextRange can be used to convert RTF to HTML and vice versa. HTML is recognized by Excel.

Comment: Could you provide some example for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends partly on what the variable "rtf" is defined as. Here is a snippet that I've used to copy RTF data to the clipboard that does paste into Excel.

```
        FlowDocument doc = CreateDoc();
        TextRange range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            range.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, Encoding.UTF8.GetString((stream as MemoryStream).ToArray()));
        }
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
```